# How to sensitivedata redacting logging in file and application in sights using serilog in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, serilog

In .Net 6.0 using sensitive data redacting and also in console its display redacting properties as well.but my question how can i log those redacting data in logfile.

when i am logging in console using below code.

```
builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(options => options.JsonWriterOptions = new JsonWriterOptions
{
    Indented = true
});
```

Comment: please share way more context as to what you are using (its unclear whether/why serilog is in the picture and/or what the overall objective is). As it stands, nobody can answer in a useful way without a lot of guessing and/or dragging information out of you. ASIDE: in general the best solution to redaction is to not put stuff that should not go into a log into the log pipeline in the first instance...

Comment: i am using below code for logs logging in file                  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()   
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File(builder.Configuration["Logging:LogFilePath"].ToString(), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    //.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights("<Your_Instrumentation_Key>")
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.EnableEnrichment();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);             but it can't logged in file

Comment: best to edit into your post, correctly formatted. One important bit is to identify what's doing the redacting - if it's outside the Serilog pipeline, then there's no magic that can make it do that etc.

Comment: How to redacting sensitive data in .net 6 and how its logging file as well as